# Magento 404 Error in Frontend and Admin When "Use Web Server Rewrites : YES"

Tags: frontend, 404

I am Using Magento 1.9.2.2 to my site.Getting index.php every url in Front end and Admin When trying to Remove index.php using Option "Use Web Server Rewrites : YES" Then in Front Url Structure Getting without index.php but when trying to open without index.php getting 404 Error.

i have downloaded fresh .htaccess from magento and uploaded to my Magento Root Directory But Not Working.Please Help me to Solve it Out

Answer (score 5):

It seems your server is not configured **mod_rewrite** module, please enable it and try.

Ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04 [Follow Step 2 — Enabling mod_rewrite]

---

Modify server directory block under server configuration file as below:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       # changed from None to FileInfo
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: mode_rewrite Enabled Already

Comment: Can you please verify **Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews**, **AllowOverride All**, **Order allow,deny** and **allow from all** is set to rewrite directory options in server configuration file.

Comment: Just i was Reading a Post Where ask to check mod_rewrite if OK then Make AllowOverride All in etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file . I have downloaded httpd.conf file . It was AllowOverride None and I just Replaced AllowOverride All but can't Replaced Asking Permission Denied to write.I am using AWS Linux . Need to give permission

Comment: If you have root user access then you can do this using **sudo** which allows you to modify **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** file

Comment: After Input Command : "sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf " press Enter

Comment: sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 

ctrl+o,Enter

Showing me  Wrote 421 lines ... Then Restart Apache .. But Still not able to Replace file httpd.conf

Showing Error "Error: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: open for write: permission denied"

Comment: Hey Jayesh Patel Will You Suggest me Where I will Input This Command

"<Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       # changed from None to FileInfo
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
</Directory>"

I am not Sure

Comment: This will set under **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** or **vhost.conf** file, but I guess you already did this. Can you please paste your server configuration snippet on _http://pastebin.com/kQZeGNkj_

Comment: configuration snippet means What have been Written in  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

I have Replaced AllowOverride None to All and Replaced httpd.conf. Just Now and Nothing Happen . Not Yet Solve

Comment: I mean to say please paste you configuration file content to given link. Is **httpd.conf** saved successfully or gives you any error?

Comment: I didn't get any error . i was not able to replace httpd.conf but now able to replace httpd.conf and made AllowOverride NONE TO All

Comment: I have pasted to this pastebin.com/kQZeGNkj

Comment: By mistake my colleague deleted that pastebin, can you please add it under your question?

Comment: Can't Paste "too long by 11149 characters"

Comment: Replace **DirectoryIndex index.html** with **DirectoryIndex index.php index.html** inside **<IfModule dir_module>** block of server configuration and restart apache service

Comment: How to do "block of server configuration"

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted. Do you want to remove **index.php** from url ?

Comment: Already mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls#15504981, please go through and configure your store

Answer (score 2):

There will be two things you need to check.

Please check. **mod_rewrite** is enable in your server. if **mode_rewrite** is enable.

Then please replace **.htaccess** with fresh magento **.htaccess**

Hope it helps you

Comment: Server mode_rewrite  in ENABLE and Replaced .htaccess with Fresh Magento ,htaccess BUT SAME Problem

Comment: @user2255224 check Catalog URL Rewrites in index section. is it indexed?